# How do I get the current script path in GNU Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

In GNU Octave, how do I get the path to the directory the script is stored in? I would like this to work regardless of the current directory.

Comment: or are you looking for `pwd`?

Comment: @Andy that won't cut it, as `pwd` returns your working directory, and you can add the directory the script is in to the path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for both Octave and Matlab:

```
file_path = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
```

The function [`mfilename`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/mfilename.html) returns the name of the script it is called from. When called with `'fullpath'`, it returns the full path to that file (including the file name and extension). [`fileparts`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/fileparts.html) extracts the path to the containing folder.

Note that this will return an empty string if called from the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where is located another script, you can also try with
the following command:

```
which("myScript");
```